# AWS Cognito not creating an authenticated user with Digits

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito, twitter-digits

I'm try to authenticate a user with Amazon Cognito and Twitter Digits. When I create the user, an unauthenticated user gets created that doesnt have any connection to the Digits login.

Here's my code:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1, identityPoolId:"us-east-1:1b21eda6-56e8-4094-a7af-XXXXXXXXXXXX")
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

        let authButton = DGTAuthenticateButton(authenticationCompletion: { (session: DGTSession?, error: NSError?) in
            if (session != nil) {

                let value = (session!.authToken)! + ";" + (session!.authTokenSecret)!
                credentialsProvider.logins = ["www.digits.com" : value]

                credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWithBlock({ (task) -> AnyObject? in
                    print(task.result)
                    print(task.error)

                    return nil
                })

                self.saveNumber((session?.phoneNumber)!)

            } else {
                print("Authentication error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
        authButton.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(authButton)
    }
```

And the code for `saveNumber`:

```
func saveNumber(number : String) {

        let syncClient = AWSCognito.defaultCognito()
        let dataset = syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("userInfo")

        dataset.setString(number, forKey: "phoneNumber")
        dataset.synchronize().continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject? in

            if task.error != nil {
                print("Uh Oh")
                print(task.error?.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                print("Yay!")
            }
            return nil
        }

    }
```

[image: Users are not being authenticated]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Which SDK version are you using?  Can you turn on verbose logging and confirm that the logins map is getting sent to the service when it calls GetCredentialsForIdentity?  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html#logging It's possible you are associating the logins with the credentialsProvider after it has obtained credentials so the identity is unauthenticated.

Comment: @behrooziAWS I'm using version 2.4.0. The only thing I'm seeing in the logs about the credentialsProvider is this: `2016-06-27 18:12:23.354[23815:2089794] AWSiOSSDK v2.4.0 [Warn] AWSCognitoIdentityService.m line:173 | __48+[AWSCognitoIdentity internalInitializeIfNeeded]_block_invoke | Could not find valid 'AWSDefaultRegionType', 'AWSCognitoRegionType', and 'AWSCognitoIdentityPoolId' values in info.plist. Unable to set the default Cognito credentials provider and service configuration. Please follow the instructions on this website...`

Answer (score 0):

Given your error message in the comments ***"Unable to set the default Cognito credentials provider and service configuration"***, it appears that you are trying to use the credentialsProvider before it is properly configured.  Move your code that initializes the credentials provider into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your **AppDelegate**.  You can access the credentials provider in your viewDidLoad with:

`AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration.credentialsProvider`

Also via logging, ensure that you have set the logins map prior to calling any operation that requires credentials such as `dataset.synchronize()`.

Comment: With `AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration.credentialsProvider`, the `.credentialsProvider` is a `AWSCredentialsProvider`, not a `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider`, which doesn't have an option to set logins.

Comment: You should be able to cast it.